# Tweepy API Search Filter

Tags: python, search, filter, tweepy

I'm currently learning how to use the Tweepy API, and is there a way to filter quoted Tweets and blocked users? I'm trying to stop search from including **quoted Tweets** and **Tweets from blocked users**. I have filtered Retweets and replies already.

Here's what I have:

`for tweet in api.search(q = 'python -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies', lang = 'en', count = 100):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter quotes, use `'-filter:quote'`